# Installation file 4-5 times bigger than the APK file

Tags: android, apk, size, filesize

I have an APK file size 14mb. Yet, installing the app on my device gives me huge 54mb.

I have reduced the size of my res assets dramatically (currently only 6 mb).
Also, I added the following lines to gradle file:

```
        release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                shrinkResources true

        }
    }
```

My dependencies are as follows:

```
dependencies {


    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.hajiyevelnur92:intentanimation:1.0'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
```

I have heard that installation file size can double, or in worst cases triple but not really get 4-5 times larger than the original APK file.

What also can cause such a huge difference in installation and APK sizes?

Comment: Did you try to analyse the apk file in android studio? It will show you what is taking space

Comment: Thank you, yet  I already used analyse APK funciton before publishing my question here. Below is my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing my dependencies I came to the conclusion that enabling this part

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.0'
```

automatically adds 20mb to my installation file.
I wish there was some warning about it from Firebase.